# drag/slide finger to perform onclick buttons- multitouch

Tags: java, android, android-layout, onclick, multi-touch

i have a game, consisting of 7 buttons , arranged such that 1 button is in the center and rest 6 around it. 
click on the buttons results in change in textview. using click can really be cumbersome for the user, therefore i would like to add functionality of dragging finger over buttons to perform onclick ..something similar to boggle type of games like -> https://market.android.com/details?id=com.ant.wordfind.client&feature=search_result

i have tried to implement the same ,problem is when i drag of finger only one button gets registered , even if i press other buttons by dragging cursor -> other button touch are just ignored.given the 
following code.

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent arg1) 
{ 
                if(arg1.getAction() ==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) 
        { 
                Button b; 
                switch (v.getId()) 
        { 
        case R.id.b1: 
        case R.id.b2: 
        case R.id.b3: 
        case R.id.b4: 
        case R.id.b5: 
        case R.id.b6: 
        case R.id.b7: 
              b = (Button)findViewById(v.getId()); 
              b.performClick(); 
                break; 
        } 
     return true; 
        }
```

am i missing somethng ? wht i want is whn buttons are touched ..they perform onclick functionality.once one button click is registered rest touches are ignored
any help would be appreciated .

i dont want something like piano/soundboard where there is continuous click of button ..but just one click as i drag finger over the button 
thanks !

Answer (score 0):

At `onTouch()`, you shouldn't always use `return true`. Return `false` if you want the subsequent actions to be captured.

> onTouch() - This returns a boolean to indicate whether your listener consumes this event. The important thing is that this event can have multiple actions that follow each other. So, if you return false when the down action event is received, you indicate that you have not consumed the event and are also not interested in subsequent actions from this event. Thus, you will not be called for any other actions within the event, such as a finger gesture, or the eventual up action event.

Ref: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html

Comment: When returning false, it works. But it fires off REALLY fast! Is there a way to say, 'rate limit' the return?